Trouble fetching unread messages from table with php query, lost a bit
So having trouble fetching the unread messages and counting them from the authenticated user in a Laravel project.
I went the traditional PHP route to try and get this working but to no avail have been working on it for a couple days and only failing.
I am calling it from a blade file.
  <?php
      $messages = DB::table('messages')
              ->where('read', false)
              ->where('receiver_id' ==  Auth::id())
              ->get();
      $counter = 0;
      foreach ($messages as $message) {

        $counter++;
      }
      echo $counter;
      ?>

I cant get it working in anyway and as of now i am getting this error
:

local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''
in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from messages where read = 0 and
`` is null)

My messages table structure:
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id');
        $table -> longText('content_sender');
        $table -> longText('nonce_sender');
        $table -> longText('content_receiver');
        $table -> longText('nonce_receiver');
        $table -> uuid('conversation_id');
        $table -> uuid('sender_id') -> nullable();
        $table -> uuid('receiver_id');
        $table -> boolean('read') ->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table -> primary('id');
        $table -> foreign('conversation_id') -> references('id') -> on('conversations') -> onDelete('cascade');
        $table -> foreign('sender_id') -> references('id') -> on('users') -> onDelete('cascade');
        $table -> foreign('receiver_id') -> references('id') -> on('users') -> onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

Would really appreciate any pointer to get this working fast as its really holding me up.
Thanks folks.

get this working fast as its really holding me up... FYI: Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?. Just so you understand, this site is not a helpdesk. See also [ask] - your title could be much more descriptive of the issue and thus useful to others (either who want to help you, or who have a similar problem). You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

I never implied this is a helpdesk, i am just asking friendly for help.
Is this not what this place is for?
Or is it to troll and go A.H. on each other or some weird gestapo style behavior?
If you have advice on my problem please add a comment if not? ---->

@Tiran100 you really honor your name huh? You don't need the == in your where clause, change it to where('receiver_id', Auth::id()), the same thing you're doing with the read column. Other than that, try to be nice when asking for help, generally gets a better response..

Thanks @geertjanknapen will give it a try.
No the name has nothing to do with it and in my opinion i asked the main question quiet nicely. :)

@geertjanknapen that did it, i kindly thank you a lot :)

Yes, and ADyson nicely pointed out how you could improve your question. No need to start going off and comparing people to trolls or, even worse, the Gestapo.

@Tiran100 I didn't say you didn't ask nicely, I said specifically that you can't ask us to do it "fast" - this is an encylopaedia, not a coding service. As per the [tour] the main objective here is to collect useful and interesting programming questions (and answers) for everyone's benefit. Solving your immediate problem is just a useful side-effect of that process, and, as such, your personal timescales are of no importance to the community. Someone could still legitimately add a new answer to this question in 5 years time.

@ADyson point taken and you are right.
Apologies :)

And then I mentioned that you could improve the quality of the post's title, that's all. If you think that makes me a fascist or secret policeman, then can I suggest reading a bit more history

Apology accepted, thankyou

But yes the answer below is correct: ->where('receiver_id' ==  Auth::id()) will resolve to ->where(true) (or perhaps ->where(false)) which of course makes no sense and doesn't map to a column in your SQL table. You should follow the syntax you used successfully and correctly in the ->where() block you wrote right above that one, in order to pass in the two values (column name, and value to compare). Laravel will build the comparison expression for you, without you needing to code it explicitly.

I think the issue is here : ->where('receiver_id' ==  Auth::id())
Where takes the column name and the value read more, here you are passing the result of 'receiver_id' === Auth::id() which is false, the code should be like this :
 <?php
      $messages = DB::table('messages')
              ->where('read', false)
              ->where('receiver_id',  Auth::id())
              ->get();
      $counter = 0;
      foreach ($messages as $message) {

        $counter++;
      }
      echo $counter;
      ?>


If you only want to get the unread messages this can be get with eloquent like:
$unread_messages = Message::where([
['receiver_id', Auth::id()],
['read',false]
])
->withCount('messages')
->get();

or
$unread_messages = Message::where('receiver_id', Auth::id())->withCount('messages',function($query){
   $query->where('read',false);
})->get();

echo $unread->count_messages


